# Multiple payment methods, multiple currencies solution

Tags: e-commerce, finance, payment-processing, banking, payment-services

We need a website where users can deposit funds to their accounts, transfer funds from one user's account to other user's account, withdraw funds. We are looking for reliable solution so that users can use several payment methods to deposit/withdraw funds and optionally use multiple currencies (so funds can be converted from one currency to another). This part of website should be similar to payments part of freelancer.com and similar websites. It means that user1 can deposit funds using PayPal, then user1 transfers part of these funds to user2 and user2 can withdraw these funds (deposited by user1 using PayPal) to user2's MoneyBookers account. Can anyone suggest solution for this? Does that mean that we need to have sufficient amounts on both PayPal and MoneyBookers or there's a way to transfer funds from our PayPal account to our MoneyBookers account (without commission) in order to process user2's withdrawal request. Does anyone know what freelancer.com and similar websites use to implement this? We plan to integrate with payoneer.com later as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to transfer money between PayPal and Moneybookers directly would be to use a Moneybookers Mastercard and deposit with that on PayPal.

The other way (PayPal to MB) is not possible directly, you will need to make a PayPal payment to a third-party (your company), that then makes an automated deposit on Moneybookers. This is possible with their API.